# Creating and displaying a Pop-up window using the Android NDK?

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, popup

How can I create and display a pop-up window using the Android NDK (i.e the equivalent of the win32 MessageBox() ) ? I took a look at what I assumed to be the the documentation of the NDK but I couldn't find it.
Thank you.

Comment: What are you doing for the rest of your UI? OpenGL?

Comment: Use AlertDialog.Builder

Answer (score 0):

See this link , i think this may help you http://www.dynadream.com/ddweb/index.php/Special_Blog?id=20