# How to create pop up window in Android Native code?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am not able to find a way to create a Pop up window in Android NDK. Can someone share some code reference or NDK API reference for creating a pop up window?
I meant in C++ and not java code for pop up window.

Comment: I think you can't with an api, but I suppose you may call java code from c++ by constructing "pieces", something like https://www.iitk.ac.in/esc101/05Aug/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/method.html

Comment: Did you see this other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675861/creating-and-displaying-a-pop-up-window-using-the-android-ndk

Comment: I do not see anything online about how to do this. You could go through the NDK and write your own, but using the JNI will probably be the fastest route. Google describes it a bit here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni
The JNI may look intimidating, but it is straightforward.

In addition, Oracle has some very well written docs on it. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html